# using bash to find next month

Tags: linux, bash, date

I am getting the current year and month via bash.  However when I try to find the next year and month I am getting errors.
prints `2019` and `05`

```
mydate=$(date +'%Y');
mymonth=$(date +'%m');
```

Both fail

```
nexty=$(date +'%Y') -d next year;
nextm=$(date +'%m') -d 'next month';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, if you really want "next year and next month" or "year+month of next month". This is a solution for the second one, but "Examine the current date only once" is good for the first one too:

Examine the current date only once:

```
date=($(date +%Y\ %m -d 'next month'))
echo "year=${date[0]}, month=${date[1]}"
```

or

```
date=$(date +%s -d 'next month')
year=$(date -d@$date +%Y)
month=$(date -d@$date +%m)
echo "$year $month"
```

Otherwise you can run into trouble at day change. Example: 1 command executed in last second of December, the other one in first second of January.

Answer (score 3):

The closing parenthesis are misplaced. Try the following:

```
nexty=$(date +'%Y' -d 'next year');
nextm=$(date +'%m' -d 'next month');
```

Comment: Possible issues if a day changes between both commands.